# MATLAB convert big-endian order bytes into floating point values

Tags: matlab, floating-point, byte, endianness

I have the following bytes stored in a vector:

```
data = [189    33   136   147]
```

These 4 bytes represent a single float in Big-endian order. How can I get this number in MATLAB?

I will need to concatenate and convert. I tried:

```
x = typecast(str2num(sprintf('%d%d%d%d',data(1),data(2),data(3),data(4))), 'single')
```

To no avail (I got `x = []`).

Comment: If you're getting these bytes from a file, you can use `fread` and `fopen` with the proper options to read the data as correct floats from the very start. If the bytes are coming from somewhere else - this probably doesn't apply...

Comment: I was just going to add this point myself, after reading the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20549518/1020470) from @horchler below, I remembered when importing video from a 32-bit UV-camera I used the low-level IO function [`fread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html) with the precision set to `'uint32=>double'` and machine format as `'ieee-be'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

great example [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/typecast.html):

```
>> dataL = typecast(uint8([189, 33, 136, 147]), 'uint32')
dataL =
   2475172285
>> dataF = double(dataL)
dataF =
   2.4752e+09
```

big to little, try [`swapbytes`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/swapbytes.html)

```
>> dataLbig = swapbytes(dataL)
dataLbig =
   3173091475
>> dataFbig = double(dataLbig)
dataFbig =
   3.1731e+09
```

Is this what you were expecting?

Comment: This lead me to the solution. Here's the answer: `x = typecast(uint8([data(4),data(3),data(2),data(1)]), 'single')`

Comment: @JDS: Or just `typecast(uint8(data(4:-1:1)),'single')`. I'm sure that you're aware that the largest four byte `uint32` is larger than `realmax('single')`? In other words, anything larger than `[255 255 127 127]` will overflow and result in `NaN`.

Answer (score 2):

I'll leave this here in case it's useful for anyone. As @MarkMikofski showed, using `typecast` and `swapbytes` is the standard method for this. However, if you your data is already floating-point, these functions can be inefficient in some cases. I use the following utility function in my video-encoding/decoding tools:

```
function x = Bit32toDouble(y)
n = numel(y);
if n >= 65536
    x = double(swapbytes(typecast(uint8(y(:)),'uint32'))).';
elseif n > 4
    x = sum(bsxfun(@times,[16777216;65536;256;1],reshape(y(:),4,n/4)));
else
    x = sum([16777216;65536;256;1].*y(:));
end
```

There are separate cases depending on the number of bytes passed in. Only when a large amount of data is processed at once is the `typecast`/`swapbytes` most efficient. If the function is called repeatedly with smaller inputs, as is common in my application, the other cases are much faster because they do every thing in Matlab's native floating-point.

Comment: Is this general to Endian order?

Comment: @JDS: Are you asking if will handle converting either big- or little- endian data? This converts groups of four bytes representing 32-bit unsigned integers (four 8-bit unsigned integers) into doubles. It assumes that doubles are encoded (that is the returned dat type) and that the bytes of the input data are in big-endian order. It will still work if run on any arbitrary sets of four bytes, but will likely return garbage. To be general or ["bi-endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Bi-endian_hardware) the function would need to be told the endianness of the data.

Comment: @JDS: By the way, If you're reading or writing files using `fread` or `fwrite`, you might look into the [`machineformat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html#inputarg_machinefmt) option that can be specified in those functions or via `fopen`. This allows you to tell those function the byte order.