# Array contents display in pairs

Tags: arrays, matlab, parsing, printf

I have an array for example: `A=[01 255 03 122 85 107];` and I want to print the contents as

```
  A=
   FF 01 
   7A 03   
   6B 55
```

Basically a read out from a memory. Is there any function in MatLab lib? I need to do this with minimum use of loops.

Comment: Looks like a [code golf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf) problem ;) - so my suggestion would be `([1,10]*reshape(A,2,[]))'` (25 characters)

Comment: `rot90(reshape(A,2,[]),3)` (24 characters) :-) @bdecaf

Comment: `A=[01 FF 03 7A 55 6B]` doesn't work with MATLAB.

Comment: so it's hex values and big endian... I guess in this question it is shown how to work with that in matlab: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20535028/matlab-convert-big-endian-order-bytes-into-floating-point-values

Comment: Post minimal workable example for the input and expected output? I guess the output makes sense, but the input you have doesn't. Is the input a char array or cell array? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @divakar .. Sorry for confusion with input array.. i corrected it  now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this -

```
str2num(num2str(fliplr(reshape(A,2,[])'),'%1d'))
```

Output -

```
ans =
    21
    43
    65
    87
```

---

If you only want to print it as characters, use it without `str2num`, like this -

```
num2str(fliplr(reshape(A,2,[])'),'%1d')
```

Output -

```
ans =
21
43
65
87
```

---

General case with zeros padding -

```
A=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 3] %// Input array
N = 3; %// groupings, i.e. 2 for pairs and so on
A = [A zeros(1,N-mod(numel(A),N))]; %// pad with zeros
out = str2num(num2str(fliplr(reshape(A,N,[])'),'%1d'))
```

Output -

```
out =
   321
   654
   987
     3
```

---

Edit for hex numbers :

```
Ar = A(flipud(reshape(1:numel(A),2,[])))
out1 = reshape(cellstr(dec2hex(Ar))',2,[])'
out2 = [char(out1(:,1)) repmat(' ',[numel(A)/2 1]) char(out1(:,2))]
```

Output -

```
out1 = 
    'FF'    '01'
    '7A'    '03'
    '6B'    '55'
out2 =
FF 01
7A 03
6B 55
```

Comment: Thanks .. can this be extended to work if array length is odd . adding zero to make it even

Comment: @crazy_bean Try this before using this code - `A = [A zeros(1,mod(numel(A),2))]`? Also, can there be two or three or more number of digits in `A`? If so, that could complicate things.

Comment: Yes the array contain 2 digits numbers only

Comment: @crazy_bean I meant can `A` have two digits numbers as elements, like - `A = [2 11 23 3 77]`?

Comment: Yes elemsts of array are always A=[02 11 23 FF 7A]. Its the 8 bit data read from a memory, so can also be in hex format

Comment: Thansk a lots.. Works perfect as of now :)

Comment: @crazy_bean Awesome! Since you have confirmed it to be working, please consider accepting the solution by clicking on the hollow checkmark next to the solution! More info - http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer