# Single-precision float to byte array in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, type-conversion

Say I have the following single-precision floating point number in Matlab

```
a = single(-2.345)
```

I would like to represent the number as an array of 4 bytes, following IEEE 754. The correct representation should be

```
b = [123, 20, 22, 192]
```

Currently, I am using `fread` and `fwrite` to do the conversion, as in

```
fid = fopen('test.dat','wb')
fwrite(fid,a,'float')
fclose(fid)

fid = fopen('test.dat','rb');
b = fread(fid)'
```

which well enough, but I suspect there is a much easier and faster way to do the conversion without reading/writing from a file.

There have been a few posts about converting a byte array to a float (such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20535028/matlab-convert-big-endian-order-bytes-into-floating-point-values)), but I'm unsure how to proceed to go in the opposite direction. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`typecast`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/typecast.html) function to cast between datatypes without changing the underlying data, i.e. reinterpret data using another type. In your case, you will want to cast from `single` to `uint8` (byte) datatype. This is done by

```
a = single(-2.345);
typecast(a,'uint8')
ans =
  123   20   22  192
```

as required.

Comment: Awesome, I figured ML would have a simple command to do this. Thank you!